# Find analogous color(s) of a color in C#

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, colors, rgb

How can I find analogous of a color in C# ?

Edit : for simplicity , the image below may help
[image]

Something like this :

```
FindAnalogous(List<Color> colorsToBeSearched , Color target)
```

or :

```
 FindAnalogous(List<Color> colorsToBeSearched , string targetHex )
```

thanks in advance

Comment: A good step to the answer would be the definition of an "analogous color".

Comment: So if `Raspberry` is sent in what would be the expected output and why?

Comment: @Magnus if Raspberry is sent  Blossom,Pixie and Bashful should be returned.